# Connecting to local AWS ip address from internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking

[image]

I've come across a project http://scrapoxy.readthedocs.io/ which I have installed on ec2 by following the quickstart (http://scrapoxy.readthedocs.io/en/master/quick_start/index.html) . If you go to

```
scrapoxy.io
```

you will see

```
Monitor at http://localhost:8889
```

Running from the command line:

```
ubuntu@ip-***-31-24-***:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
36cd618ff85d        fabienvauchelles/scrapoxy   "/bin/sh -c 'scrap..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:8888-8889->8888-8889/tcp   stoic_roentgen
```

Based on 0.0.0.0:8888-8889->8888-8889/tcp , I was hoping I might be able to access the monitoring address by using my ec2 node's public dns and the port 8889:

```
ec2-**-84-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8889
```

but when I open this address with firefox locally, the connection times out. Is there a way to access the local process from the public internet?

edit:

no, I didn't, my security groups look like:

[image]

When I open the forward-proxy group which I have created for this project I see:

[image]

I'm not experienced with AWS, should I add it here?

Comment: Have you added that port to the security group of your EC2?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: definitely before you move you have to set FW == security group, and apply for this EC2 instance

Comment: Your question "Connecting to local AWS ip address from internet", You cannot access your service from internet using your local/private ip... use public IP. which AWS allotted for you.

Comment: I think I was trying that by doing ec2-**-84-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8889

Comment: which one public or private IP?

Comment: Regarding "you have to set FW == security group, and apply for this EC2 instance " -  How is this done?

Comment: I was using the Public DNS

Comment: Have you applied that security group to the instance? and ensure that your firewall not blocks 8889 port by creating an inbound rule on the firewall for port 8889.

Comment: OK guys, Now I understand, I went to my instance then clicked - Actions -> Networking  -> change security groups , and attached the right security group and it started working immediately.